# How to uninstall Electrum?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, bitcoin

I use Electrum as Bitcoin Wallet, and I want to update it. The best way to do it, I think, would be to uninstall the old version and install the new one. How can I do that?

I use the 16.04 version of Xubuntu.

Comment: How did you install it ? Through Software Center or how ?

Comment: Through  sudo pip3 install https://download.electrum.org/3.0.5/Electrum-3.0.5.tar.gz  (I didnt even know there is an Software Center version haha)

Comment: `sudo pip3 uninstall <packagenane>` ?

Comment: @SorenA Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove electrum
sudo purge electrum
```

You may still have a folder in your  home directory named `.electrum` which should be removed manually.